# Xcode библиотека поиска WiFi iOS 7

Tags: c++, xcode, iphone, ios7

Собственно, проблема в том, что [библиотка SOLStumbler (для поиска беспроводных сетей)](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) не работает на iOS 7. Подскажите пожалуйста, где что нужно подправить?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html посмотрите, может быть полезным

Comment: iFreeman, к сожалению это не то) нужн не api на подключение, а именно получить список сетей маки и т д! то есть по умолчанию это закрыто и возможно только на устройстве с джейлом! Нужна та либа которую использует приложение WifiFoFum